# Windows 7 Guest account

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am somewhat new to Windows and need some very basic help. How do I enable the Windows 7 Guest account on Windows 7 so that someone can temporarily use my computer without me having to create a separate account for them? Can someone please point out the exact steps to follow?

Comment: Which edition of W7? Home?, Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you don't have Windows 7 Starter, it should be as simple as, following the directions below.  If you do have Windows 7 Starter you will need to create an user account for this purpose since the Guest account does not exist.

> 1. Open User Accounts by clicking `Control Panel`, clicking `User Accounts`, and then clicking `User Accounts` again.
> 2. Click `Manage User Accounts`.
> 3. Click the `Advanced` tab, click `Advanced`, and then click `Users`.
> 4. Double-click `Guest`.
> 5. In the Guest Properties dialog box, clear the `Account is disabled`, check box.
> 6. Click `OK`.

[Turn the guest account on or off](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-guest-account-on-off#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

If you want someone to have temporary access to your computer, you can create a guest account. People using the guest account can't install software or hardware, change settings, or create a password. Because the guest account allows a user to log on to a network, browse the Internet, and shut down the computer, you should disable the guest account when it isn't being used
Turn the guest account on or off.

Please refer to the following link to turn on guest account.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-guest-account-on-off#1TC=windows-7

Best regards.